# Laravel, Auth controller doesn't exist at app/http/controllers or anywhere

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have recently installed laravel , and started a new project . after creating the laravel project (tried twice : through laravel new command and  composer create-project  ) all is set , but the problem is that i don't find  **Laravel, Auth controller doesn't exist at app/http/controllers   or anywhere !!**
i could not understand why ?

Comment: Did you run the command `php artisan make:auth`?

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel6+` versions uses `laravel/ui`  for authentication.

Run the below commands to install `laravel/ui`  and generate `authentication`

```
composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

[Laravel6 -> authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

If you are using `Laravel5` or less then use below command to generate the same:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

[Laravel5 -> authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)